# Why does git rebase always conflict?

Tags: git, git-rebase

Every time I try to rebase my branch, I get merge conflicts because some changes in my local repo conflict. The frustrating part is that those changes had been undone in subsequent commits.

Once again, I resolve them, commit and push my changes and everything is fine.

Then, next time I try to rebase the very same conflicts occur in the same files that I had resolved.

Why is this happening?

How can I fix it so these old commits don't cause merge conflicts again?

Comment: Can you list out a short example of the commands you use from start to finish that exhibit this problem. It is my understanding that rebase should not always be used with Git.

Comment: Need more context, please add more details to your question.

Answer (score 5):

please use following command to remember conflicts resolution

```
git rerere
```